# Why a fully working web site gives a 405 error when queried using curl?

Tags: curl, http-status-code-405

I have a web app running on my LAN, and from the same subnet I can access it easily using any browser on any client with a simple http://< IP >/

Nothing special. Works all the time.

But when I try the following curl command:

`curl -I http://<IP>/`

I get his response from curl:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Allow: GET
Content-Length: 23
Date: Fri, 21 May 2021 17:11:59 GMT
Server: Python/3.8 aiohttp/3.7.4.post0
```

I was expecting a 200 OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the wrong option `-I` which is an alias for `--head`, that is different from the default `-X GET`.

Fot that reason the response show you that **HEAD** method in not allowed (405), and the only accepted is **GET**, so you have to rewrite the command as `curl http://<IP>/`.

---

### **Edit***

To get only the status code, in order to test the service health, you should rewrite the command as follow:

```sh
curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" http://<IP>/
```

The result will be a string which contains the http response status code.

Comment: No, that doesn't work. 
I tried that and it just dumped the whole web page at me.
My goal is to use this curl command just to check if the web server is alive and well (indicated normally by a 200 OK) which I extract in a YAML/JSON and use in an automation script to send alarm if the response differs from 200 OK.

Comment: I understand. Now I am on mobile phone, so I cannot write full code. Simply search for the CURL parameter to print only the http status code and your problem may be solved!

Comment: Great!  That worked 
Thank you so very much !!

Comment: I am Happy to have helped you. Please set my answer as resolution.

Comment: Excellent answer! I had to add `\n` after `%{http_code}` though.